# Highest and lowest possible result of this javascript expression?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

What is the highest number this javascript expression can evaluate to? What is the lowest number? Why?

```
+(''+Math.random()).substring(2)
```

*Extra credit:* How many different values can the expression evaluate to? Can it be every value from the minimum to the maximum, or are some intermediate values not obtainable due to rounding issues?

---

**Response** to Daniel's answer (deleted, was 10000000000000000 max, 0 min):

I was playing around in Chrome's console and got this:

```
    Math.random();

>> 0.00012365682050585747

    '12365682050585747'.length

>> 17

    12365682050585747 > 10000000000000000

>> true
```

... so 10000000000000000 can't be the max!

Comment: @no: I guess it depends on what the precision of numbers returned by Math.random is. I thought it was 16 or 17 digits. I don't even know anymore :(. How'd you get this question by the way?

Comment: @Daniel: it just popped into my head... I use something like that (with a letter prepended) to create random id attributes for temporary dom elements sometimes, and I wondered how big the numbers could get.

Comment: Depends on the precision of the `float` number. Although you can see 0.00012365682050585747 with 20 decimal places, is it possible you could get 0.00012365682050585747 + 0.00000000000000000001? Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Comment: This all depends on how the implementation does its rounding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the random number is generated, and how the number will be converted to string. The ECMAScript spec doesn't specify both of these.

In practice, the number will have at most 17 significant figures, so the maximum should be at most 10<sup>17</sup>.

The spec does specify that a number will be displayed in decimal form (instead of scientific form) when the exponent is between -6 and 20 (10<sup>-6</sup> ≤ x < 10<sup>21</sup>), so we just need to restrict our attention on numbers in [10<sup>-6</sup>, 1) when trying to seek the maximum exhaustively.

However, in this range a number must be representable as *s* × 2<sup>*e*</sup>, where 1 ≤ *s* ≤ 2 − 2<sup>-52</sup> with a precision of Δ*s* = 2<sup>-52</sup> and -20 ≤ *e* ≤ -1. The spec recommends that `ToNumber(ToString(x)) == x`, so the number should be precise down to 2<sup>-52+*e*</sup> for a given *e*. Thus the "17-digit" number with (2 − *n* × 2<sup>-52</sup>) × 2<sup>*e*</sup> with the smallest *n* will be the biggest number representable with a given *e*, after chopping the initial `0.`.

```
             v                 
(-20) 0.0000019073486328124998
(-19) 0.0000038146972656249996
(-18) 0.0000076293945312499975 (n=3)
(-17)  0.000015258789062499998
(-16)  0.000030517578124999997
(-15)  0.000061035156249999986 (n=2)
(-14)   0.00012207031249999999
(-13)   0.00024414062499999997
(-12)   0.00048828124999999995
(-11)    0.0009765624999999999 (always 16-digit?)
(-10)    0.0019531249999999998
(-9)     0.0039062499999999996
(-8)     0.0078124999999999965 (n=4)
(-7)      0.015624999999999998
(-6)      0.031249999999999997
(-5)      0.062499999999999986 (n=2)
(-4)       0.12499999999999999
(-3)       0.24999999999999997
(-2)       0.49999999999999994
(-1)        0.9999999999999999 (always 16-digit?)
```

From here we know that the absolute maximum is **78,124,999,999,999,965**.

---

`Math.random()` can return any nonnegative numbers in the interval [0, 1), so the safe minimum is -324 from `5e-324` (the smallest subnormal number in double precision is 4.94 × 10<sup>-324</sup>).

Comment: Actually, I think it's "Math.random() can return any positive numbers in the interval `[0, 1)` - [0 inclussive, 1 exclussive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) "

Comment: if it will have 17 significant figures, shouldn't the maximum be 10^17-1? But that would mean it came from a fraction `0.999...` which is equal to 1 -- so it can't be more than 10^17-2, right?

Comment: Also I'm totally lost on the 324 stuff, do you have a reference for that somewhere?

Comment: @no: Some numbers will be shown with 16 figures, so that's not always true. 10^17 is just an upper bound, not the tightest one; For where the 324 comes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format.

Comment: Thanks, Kenny, will check it out. Definitely noticed most of the numbers have at most 16 digits, the 17th seems to be used for rounding oddities. BTW I just got `0.999...` (16 nines) like this: `.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1` ... so maybe I'm wrong on the second part of my first comment on this answer.

Comment: `Math.random()` just returned `46789122046902776` in my console, and that is much bigger than `19531249999999998`

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's right but it sure is convincing. I ran some much less clever tests (dividing 1 by 2 through 10000, chopping the `0.`, and then sorting for the largest result) and the highest number I saw was around 7e16... I'm going to go ahead and mark this correct.

Answer (score 2):

For me the highest number is 1/0 (===Infinity) and the lowest obviously -1/0 (in Chromium browser).

Edit: You can also try parse a number from string to see which evaluates to Infinity.

```
var a = "1";
while(parseInt(a)!==Infinity) a=a+"0";
alert("Length of the highest number is: " + (a.length-1));
```

309 for me.

Comment: Why here is said "309 for me"? Is it so that we cannot trust that the highest number is always the same, so has it some machine/browser dependencies?